# Program crashes without error message

Tags: c++, qt, loops, crash

I am using the Qt Creator (Community) to learn how to code.
I have an assignment to calculate the roots of a function, and I tried using the code I found [here](http://www.bragitoff.com/2015/08/c-program-for-bisection-method-to-find-the-roots-of-an-equation/) in a Qt Widgets Project.
When I try to run the program, Qt didn't detect any errors.
However, my program crashes whenever I try to show the results using on_pushButton_clicked().
My lecturer suspects there should be an open loop somewhere but I don't see any.
Any help would be very much appreciated.
Code below:

```
double function1(double q)
{
double ab = ((q*q*q)+(9*q*q)-(15*q)+98)*(sin(q));
return ab;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText(tr("%1").arg(func1()));
}

double MainWindow::func1()
{    
    std::setprecision(4);
    double precision = 0.001;
    double a = -10;
    double b = -9;
    double product = function1(a)*function1(b);
    double absolute = fabs(a-b);
    double e = 0;
    if (product>0)
    {
        ++a;
        ++b;
    }
    else
    {
        while (absolute >= precision)
        {
            e = (a + b) / 2;
            double fa = function1(a);
            double fe = function1(e);
            if (fe == 0)
            {
                return e;
                break;
            }
            if (fa*fe>0)
            {
                a = e;
            }
            else if (fa*fe<0)
            {
                b = e;
            }
        }
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Where **exactly** does it crash? If you suspect that it crashes in `on_pushButton_clicked` (if you were using debugger, you would know, rather than suspect), then, are all of the pointers used there, non-null?

Comment: Fairly common. If you expected the crash enough to put in an error message, odds are you would have fixed the bug instead.

Comment: never absolute and precision are updated...  so why you are comparing it?

Comment: thanks F.bernal, that was the problem after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try printing out the values of *absolute* and  *precision* everytime this loop happens:

> while (absolute >= precision)

.
That should help you figure it out.

Comment: So the problem is as F.bernal mentioned above, but I still don't get why absolute doesn't get updated everytime I change the value of 'a' or 'b' in the if else loop though.

Comment: @Shironats It sounds like you might be coming from a functional language. In a procedural one like C/C++, your variables don't get updated like you're assuming. You have to re-calculate it.

Comment: I see, thanks a bunch for clearing that up for me Keith.

Answer (score 1):

If the program crashes when you click the button that "calls" on_pushButton_clicked, then it something wrong inside this slot.

Firstly, are all heap memory objects created previously with a new statement (in particular *label*)?

PS: you can remove the *break* instruction, function has already exited the while loop due to *return* in the line before.